# fb.logout() special permission

Tags: php, facebook, permissions

In order to use the `fb.logout();` function to logout users from my website and from facebook, I need to ask for some special permission. I have been searching for three days but couldn't find the permission required to use that function. 
Can anyone tell me what permission to ask in the scope?

And also, is this way correct to log a user out from the website and from facebook:

```
<a href="<?php echo $website_url; ?>/index.php?action=logout" onclick="FB.logout();">Log out</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: You don’t need any special permission – you just need a valid user access token.

Comment: where to get that? i am using javascript sdk.

Comment: By calling `FB.login` first …

Comment: I have done that. I can login via facebook by calling fb.login but I can not understand how to use the fb.logout function... 

this is what I have:

http://pastebin.com/QrMq0Pfb if pastebin is not accepted, tell me where to paste my code

Comment: Please post relevant(!) code parts in your question, and also describe what your problem with this code is.

Comment: simple, it does not logout the user from the website. i think the problem is with the fb.logout function

Comment: FB.logout logs the user out of facebook.com, anything on your website you have to do yourself. In the FB.logout callback, redirect to a script of yours that calls the PHP SDKs `destroySession` method explicitly.